# SQL Query to check ALL days exist between a date range

Tags: sql, date, range

I have a table of Prices with a start date, end date and price. I want a search to pass in a date range and return whether a price exists for all days in that range. The date range can span multiple prices, just not have any gaps in between.

Is this possible?

```
Prices
startDate datetime
endDate datetime
price

DECLARE @startDate datetime = '2010-04-01',
        @endDate datetime = '2010-04-30'

SELECT * FROM Prices WHERE @startDate BETWEEN startDate AND endDate...
```

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of a question asked here many times.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271595/getting-dates-between-a-range-of-dates

Comment: Thanks, I obviously wasn't searching for the right thing.

Comment: I actually think it is different. You don't need to find out all the dates to answer this query.

Comment: I think you're right.  it's not a duplicate.  Why can't I reverse my vote to close?

Comment: Ah yes I thought that answer would help but it might not be exactly what I'm looking for. I'm using SQL 2008. I just need to check if there's a gap between the given date range in the Prices table.

Comment: Then this could be answered by this other stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025688/calculate-missing-date-ranges-and-overlapping-date-ranges-between-two-dates

Answer (score 2):

Add a grouping to your query with a having statement :

```
HAVING COUNT(*) = DATEDIFF(DAY,@StartDate,@EndDae)+1
```