# Find total number of hours between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I know there are so many overlapping query questions already been answered but none of them were able to resolve the issue I'm having:

We need to find out the total number of hours between the lowest start_date and highest end_date, considering the overlapping range as well.

```
Start_Date      End_Date
3/5/2010 11:27  3/5/2010 13:04 -  Need to include
3/5/2010 11:29  3/5/2010 11:55 -  Can exclude ( overlapping)
3/5/2010 13:13  3/5/2010 13:37 -  Need to include
3/5/2010 13:13  3/5/2010 13:37 -  Duplicate
3/5/2010 14:55  3/5/2010 15:22 -  Need to include
3/5/2010 14:55  3/5/2010 15:22 -  Duplicate
3/5/2010 15:15  3/5/2010 17:45 -  Overlapping with above since it starts at 15.15, 7 minutes before the previous end_date
```

thanks in advance
John D

```
enter code here
```

Comment: What is your expected result, based on the data provided?  You state you want the total number of hours, but are you really after the number of elapsed hours based on the start & end values?

Comment: Total no of hours should be 295 minutes = 4.91 hours

Comment: It seems what you want to say is you want the total number of hours *included* in any of the rows.  So, for example, if you have one row with hours 1-5 (4 hours) and another row with hours 8-10 (another 2 hours), you don't want the full time from 1 to 10, you want 4 plus 2, because no row covered 5-8.

Do you have any ability to write this in a real programming language like c# instead of just straight TSQL?

Comment: I think you're off by 4 minutes, it should be 291 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, MIN(Start_Date), MAX(End_Date)) AS [Diff]
  FROM [table]
```

MSDN `datediff` page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258269%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Comment: thanks...but we need to consider the overlapping range as well. The above code will not yield the correct result.

Comment: Then I cannot get what you actually mean :-S

Comment: First row difference 97 minutes

Comment: "First row difference" ? There's only one row in the result. And it's in hours, as originally asked, not minutes like you're now suggesting. Basically it calculates `DATEDIFF(hour, 11:27, 17:45)` and therefore overlapping ranges are counted only once.

Answer (score 1):

Well that was an interesting and fun problem to work on.  +1

So lets start up with a setup:

```
CREATE TABLE d (start_dt datetime, end_dt datetime)
INSERT INTO d VALUES ('3/5/2010 11:27', '3/5/2010 13:04')
INSERT INTO d VALUES ('3/5/2010 11:29', '3/5/2010 11:55')
INSERT INTO d VALUES ('3/5/2010 13:13', '3/5/2010 13:37')
INSERT INTO d VALUES ('3/5/2010 13:13', '3/5/2010 13:37')
INSERT INTO d VALUES ('3/5/2010 14:55', '3/5/2010 15:22')
INSERT INTO d VALUES ('3/5/2010 14:55', '3/5/2010 15:22')
INSERT INTO d VALUES ('3/5/2010 15:15', '3/5/2010 17:45')
```

Here is the code to actually calculate it, all via TSQL:

```
-- Create a cursor that we will use to loop over all the items in the base table
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT start_dt, end_dt FROM d
-- Temp variables to store each rows data
DECLARE @start_dt datetime, @end_dt datetime
-- Temp table to hold the "adjusted" rows
DECLARE @d TABLE (id int identity, start_dt datetime, end_dt datetime)
OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @start_dt, @end_dt
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- Start by deleting any rows contained entirely within the current rows timeframe
    DELETE FROM @d WHERE start_dt BETWEEN @start_dt AND @end_dt AND end_dt BETWEEN @start_dt     AND @end_dt

    DECLARE @id_start_in int = -1, @id_end_in int = -1
    SELECT @id_start_in = id FROM @d WHERE @start_dt BETWEEN start_dt AND end_dt
    SELECT @id_end_in = id FROM @d WHERE @end_dt BETWEEN start_dt AND end_dt

    -- If our start and end dates are not contained in any other set, add it as a new row
    IF (@id_start_in = -1 AND @id_end_in = -1)
        INSERT INTO @d (start_dt, end_dt) VALUES (@start_dt, @end_dt)

    -- If our start date and end dates are both contained in the same row, ignore because we are overlapping that row

    -- If our start date and end dates are in two different rows, we combine those two
    -- For example if there are 3 rows, 1-3, 2-5, 4-6, we actually have full coverage from 1-6
    IF (@id_start_in != @id_end_in AND @id_start_in != -1 AND @id_end_in != -1)
    BEGIN
        -- Expand the start row to end at the same time the row our end time is in
        UPDATE @d SET end_dt = (SELECT end_dt FROM @d WHERE id = @id_end_in) WHERE id = @id_start_in
        -- Delete the row our end time is in
        DELETE FROM @d WHERE id = @id_end_in
    END

    -- If our start date is contained in a row but our end date isnt, extend the existing row
    -- to end at our end date
    IF (@id_start_in != -1 AND @id_end_in = -1)
        UPDATE @d SET end_dt = @end_dt WHERE id = @id_start_in

    -- If our end date is contained in a row but our start date isnt, extend the existing row
    -- to start at our start time
    IF (@id_start_in = -1 AND @id_end_in != -1)
        UPDATE @d SET start_dt = @start_dt WHERE id = @id_end_in

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @start_dt, @end_dt
END
CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur

-- Show the end table
SELECT start_dt, end_dt, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, start_dt, end_dt) FROM @d
-- Sum up to get the minutes and calculate the hours
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, start_dt, end_dt)) AS MINUTES, CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, start_dt, end_dt)) AS DECIMAL) / 60 AS HOURS FROM @d
```

Answer (score 0):

Being inspired by [this answer about flattening date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025688/calculate-missing-date-ranges-and-overlapping-date-ranges-between-two-dates/1028040#1028040), I came up with this:

```
-- Required function to flatten the time ranges
-- Assumes the end date is after the start.
CREATE FUNCTION Ranges(@startOfRange DATETIME, @endOfRange DATETIME)
RETURNS @rangesTable TABLE (
    [start] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [end] DATETIME NOT NULL
    )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @startTime DATETIME
    DECLARE @endTime DATETIME
    DECLARE @m_start DATETIME
    DECLARE @m_end DATETIME

    DECLARE cursorSpans CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT [Start_Time], [End_Time]
        FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
        ORDER BY [Start_Time], [End_Time]

    OPEN cursorSpans

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursorSpans INTO @startTime, @endTime

    SET @m_start = @startTime
    SET @m_end = @endTime

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursorSpans INTO @startTime, @endTime

        IF @startTime > @m_end
        BEGIN
            -- Only insert a new record if the current date range does not overlap the previous one.
            INSERT INTO @rangesTable
            VALUES(@m_start, @m_end)

            SET @m_start = @startTime
        END
        SET @m_end = CASE WHEN @endTime > @m_end THEN @endTime ELSE @m_end END
    END

    -- Handle the final date range
    IF @m_start IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @rangesTable
        VALUES(@m_start, @m_end)
    END

    CLOSE cursorSpans
    DEALLOCATE cursorSpans

    RETURN
END
GO

-- Get the total minute difference between the start and end of each range, then total them up.
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [Start], [End]))
FROM Ranges('2010-03-05 11:00:00', '2010-03-05 18:00:00')
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the table that Jeff Wright provided:

```
CREATE TABLE d (start_dt datetime, end_dt datetime)
INSERT INTO d VALUES ('3/5/2010 11:27', '3/5/2010 13:04')
INSERT INTO d VALUES ('3/5/2010 11:29', '3/5/2010 11:55')
INSERT INTO d VALUES ('3/5/2010 13:13', '3/5/2010 13:37')
INSERT INTO d VALUES ('3/5/2010 13:13', '3/5/2010 13:37')
INSERT INTO d VALUES ('3/5/2010 14:55', '3/5/2010 15:22')
INSERT INTO d VALUES ('3/5/2010 14:55', '3/5/2010 15:22')
INSERT INTO d VALUES ('3/5/2010 15:15', '3/5/2010 17:45')
```

It's time to have fun with [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx):

```
with ranges as (
    select d.start_dt,d.end_dt from d
    union all
    select r1.start_dt,r2.end_dt from d r1 inner join ranges r2 on r1.start_dt < r2.start_dt and r1.end_dt >= r2.start_dt
    union all
    select r1.start_dt,r2.end_dt from ranges r1 inner join d r2 on r2.end_dt > r1.end_dt and r2.start_dt <= r1.end_dt
), maxrange as (
    select start_dt,MAX(end_dt) as end_dt from ranges group by start_dt
), minmaxrange as (
    select MIN(start_dt) as start_dt,end_dt from maxrange group by end_dt
)
select SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,start_dt,end_dt)) from minmaxrange
```

The ranges CTE finds all of the overlapping periods. The maxrange CTE then finds the latest end_dt for a particular start_dt, and the minmaxrange finds the earliest start_dt for a particular end_dt. Together, these two eliminate overlaps and duplicates. Finally, we ask for the sum of the differences, in minutes. Result is 291 minutes.